# Expandable listview with pagination for each group

Tags: android, pagination, expandablelistview

I have to add pagination to each group of expandable list view. I have to load new data for each group separately. I don't want to add common pagination.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should add some code to your post so that the community can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added(one extra child load more type) as last child in each group of child list. and added condition in getChildView() method to check row is child type or load more type.

its working now...

Comment: You should add a code snippet to help other people in the community.